# Give examples of a formal power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n x^n$ centered at $0$ with radius of convergence $1$.

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

Give examples of a formal power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n x^n$ centered at $0$ with radius of convergence $1$, which

(a) diverges at both $x=1$ and $x=-1$;

(b) diverges at $x=1$ but converges at $x= -1$;

(c) converges at $x=1$ but diverges at $x=-1$;

(d) converges at both $x =1 $ and $x =-1$;

(e) converges pointwise on $(-1, 1)$, but does not converges uniformly on $(-1, 1)$.

For (a), $c_n$ can be any constant real number or $c_n = n$ also works.

For (b), $c_n = \frac1n$ works.

For (c), $c_n = (-1)^n \frac1n$ works.

I have difficulty in coming up with examples for (d) and (e). Can you give me some hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\sum \frac 1 {n^{2}} x^{n}$ has radius of convergence $1$ and it converges at both $x=1$ and $x=-1$.

$\sum  n x^{n}$ converges for $|x|<1$ but the convergence is not uniform since the general term does not tend to $0$ uniformly (as seen by putting $x=\frac 1 {n^{1/n}}$).